# Align elements on same line

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to create a custom radio buttons which sometimes will be images and sometimes a square faking a background color.

This is what I have at the moment:

**HTML**

```
<div class="radio-inline radio-img">
  <input type="radio" name="cat" id="cat1" />
  <label for="cat1">
    <img src="//placekitten.com/150/150" />
  </label>
</div>

<div class="radio-inline radio-img">
  <input type="radio" name="cat" id="cat2" />
  <label for="cat2">
    <img src="//placekitten.com/151/151" />
  </label>
</div>

<div class="radio-inline radio-color">
  <input type="radio" name="cat" id="cat3" />
  <label for="cat3">
    <span></span>
  </label>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
input[type="radio"] + label span {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 48px;
  height: 48px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}

input[type="radio"] + label span {
  background-color: #292321;
}

input[type="radio"]:checked + label span:before {
  content: '\2714';
  color: #fff;
  padding: 5px
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GmNEvM

I couldn't figure it out how to align the two types! How can I do this?

Thanks!

Comment: just a remark: In your codepen you misspelled `position: absolute` in the last CSS rule. If you correct that, the whole thing becomes a little chaotic...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, inline block elements align themselves to the `baseline`. Use `vertical-align: middle;` for the `div`.

```css
.radio-inline {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 20px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

**Preview**

[image: preview]

**Preview: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/aWByaE**

Comment: Thanks, is there a way to set it up as the same width and height, i'm using padding because since it's a background color there's no content

Comment: @Trxplz0 Use height and width.

Answer (score 1):

checkout this: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YVpxmg

```
input[type=radio] + label>span {
    display: inline-block;
    background: red;
    width: 68px;
    height: 68px;
}
```

you can set the `display` of any element to either `block` or `inline-block` and set a width and height for that element!

I've updated the codepen to reflect the changes.

Answer (score 0):

Vertically align it the way you like cuz they are inline-blocks. And make the span in the third box a block element. See Below

```css
.radio-inline {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 20px;
  vertical-align: top;/**Added*/
}

input[type=radio] {
  position: absolute;
  left: -9999px;
}

input[type=radio]:checked + label>img, input[type=radio]:checked + label>span {
  box-shadow: 0 0 3px 3px #000;
}

input[type=radio] + label>img {
  width: 68px;
  height: 68px;
  transition: 250ms all;
}

input[type=radio] + label>span {
  position: absoltue;
  background: red;
  top: -20px;
  left: 0;
  padding-right: 34px;
  padding-left: 34px;
  padding-top: 34px;
  padding-bottom: 34px;
  display: block;/**Added*/
}
```

```html
<div class="radio-inline radio-img">
  <input type="radio" name="cat" id="cat1" />
  <label for="cat1">
    <img src="//placekitten.com/150/150" />
  </label>
</div>

<div class="radio-inline radio-img">
  <input type="radio" name="cat" id="cat2" />
  <label for="cat2">
    <img src="//placekitten.com/151/151" />
  </label>
</div>

<div class="radio-inline radio-color">
  <input type="radio" name="cat" id="cat3" />
  <label for="cat3">
    <span></span>
  </label>
</div>
```